# Integrating Windows/OSX/Linux authentication against Linux Server (web server)

Tags: linux, authentication, oauth, active-directory, ldap

I have an *application* that have to authenticate against a **Linux Machine**. Clients run in *Windows / Linux / Mac*, and must authenticate using user credentials under Windows/Linux/Mac aganist  Linux Machine.

My question is about, If I can use user credential to authenticate in Linux Machine as long as  , for instance Linux Server was connected to **LDAP ActiveDirectory** in Windows Server.

More conscious:
I'm a user authenticated in Windows under **ActiveDirectory**, and my App connect to a Linux Machine and send user credentials to authenticate, so, It's possible that Linux Server can connect to **LDAP** services in Windows Domain and validate the credentials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking whether in general it is possible for an app running on a Linux web-server to have users authenticate against AD on a windows box: yes.

That can be done, I've done it both perl & PHP in the past. Only caveats I see is that you a) want to make sure you use SSL from the browser to the webserver and b) make sure that the code won't leak/log credentials on the Linux box.

Comment: Well, my client application is done in python and it connect to a service in a Linux Server. I want send Windows Credentials to Linux Service and authenticate this user data on LDAP under Linux Machine. Is it prossible??

Comment: What is "a Linux server"?  In your header you say web server; do you have control over the web-app?  Is the web-server on the same network as your AD machine?  As I said: with control over the web app it can be done.

Comment: Linux server is the main machine where is the main software, and have centralized authentication management.

Comment: Do you have an example?